# handling showModalDialog window in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I am using Selenium- JAVA to automate my application. In my application, when we click on a particular button, it actually opening a window using showModalDialog command. When we open a window using showModalDialog the java-script execution gets suspended till the window gets closed.

Problem No :1 
in Internet Explorer(7,8,9), i am getting permission denied error upon clicking. I also tried executing javascript. For this also i got permission denied error. Any idea about this issue?

Problem No:2
In Firefox, i executed the same script and it is working fine. But the problem here is execution is suspended and it will not execute the other commands till the model window gets closed.:( How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to do  modifications in selenium browser bot js-IEBrowserBot.prototype.modifyWindowToRecordPopUpDialogs to handle the modal window-this will help [Try this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536759%28VS.85%29.aspx). Or try using webdriver.
Can you post the application HTML you are getting this error on?